# Voice and Music detection using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, voice-detection

im currently working a chrome extension that can cancels background music of videos played in the browser. I found on this forum a way to detect if the browser is playing music or not (first step), it work on a browser but its not actually working for extension.
So i would like to know if someone knew a node package that can detect sound from browser. In the same way, if someone knows a package can "split" music and voice from a video (in JS) I am interested.

Have a good day!